ffmpeg - convert MP4 to 2010 Lumix playable MJPEG
I'm new to ffmpeg and ffprobe, I started using it to convert videos to show on 3DS and DSi for an art project.
Now I want to show my own videos on a Panasonic LUMIX digicam (DMC-FT2)(JPN), but have had trouble getting the device to play the video.
The digi takes videos in AVCHD Lite and Motion JPEG.
I've tried online converting mp4 to the respective formats + changing file name, but the device only recognises that it's there — refuses to/can't play it.
I also tried using this code to convert to MJPEG: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mjpeg -q:v 2 -an output.mjpeg
But no luck! Changed the filename to match the others, the camera recognised the file is there, but can't play it.
So I used this code to get the information of a MJPEG video taken on the digi: /opt/ffmpeg/ffprobe file.mp4 -show_streams  -select_streams v  -print_format json/opt/ffmpeg/ffprobe file.mp4 -show_streams  -select_streams v  -print_format json
and got the following, is it possible to convert my own video (mp4) to these settings? So that it can play on the device? If so how?
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331972
    compatible_brands: qt  pana
    creation_time   : 2024-08-21T21:54:59.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12287 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 11083 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2024-08-21T21:54:59.000000Z
        vendor_id       : pana
        encoder         : Photo - JPEG
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2024-08-21T21:54:59.000000Z
        vendor_id       : pana
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mjpeg",
            "codec_long_name": "Motion JPEG",
            "profile": "Baseline",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "jpeg",
            "codec_tag": "0x6765706a",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480,
            "coded_width": 640,
            "coded_height": 480,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "film_grain": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "pix_fmt": "yuvj420p",
            "level": -99,
            "color_range": "pc",
            "color_space": "bt470bg",
            "chroma_location": "center",
            "refs": 1,
            "id": "0x1",
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "time_base": "1/30",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 180,
            "duration": "6.000000",
            "bit_rate": "11083093",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "180",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0,
                "non_diegetic": 0,
                "captions": 0,
                "descriptions": 0,
                "metadata": 0,
                "dependent": 0,
                "still_image": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2024-08-21T21:54:59.000000Z",
                "language": "eng",
                "vendor_id": "pana",
                "encoder": "Photo - JPEG"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Show full ffprobe for the input as well as the working Lumix file, without -select_streams v
